# Bug in MacOS Mojave GUI: No any password works

Tags: macos, gui, macos-mojave

Yesterday after I rebooted my Macbook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) Mojave system, I found myself unable to login on all my local accounts in the GUI. Today I used the following commands.

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
    /sbin/mount -uw /
    launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
    passwd <Username>
```

Then I tried to see if password has been changed (which isn't)

```
Old Password: ~ // entered the right password
New Password: ~ // entered a one-character string (to see if old password has not been changed)
Retype Password: ~ 
..<ENTER>..
passwd: Failed global policy "com.apple.defaultpasswordpolicy"
Password change failed because password does not meet minimum quality requirements. 

//Note: Line 1 is correct , stuck at line 2


Old Password: ~ < entered a wrong password // catch error at first line
New Password: ~ < again entered a one-character string
Retype Password ~
..<ENTER>..
AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 15 sel: 75: ret: e00002ce '-536870194', -1, 100000)
passwd: Credentials could not be verified, username or password is invalid.
```

Results by comparing both responses: **password has not been changed, so this isn't the problem.** plus I have this problem with multiple local accounts, password doesn't work in GUI.

What I tried next is using an external keyboard to see if the layout isn't incorrect, but the layout was correct as I could type a row of keys in the right order in Recovery Mode Safari.

I pressume this is a bug in the GUI, possibly. Does anyone know a fix for this?

**UPDAT:E** I installed the OS again without removing any data, and that seemed to be the solution. Although I don't know what caused this.

Comment: Have you tried the "resetpassword" command in Terminal in Recovery Mode? This should trigger a GUI pane where you'll see a "Forgot all passwords" link. You can choose a different password, and restart your Mac.

Comment: @Didier Thanks i've tried resetpassword but still doesn't work. Can it be a problem in pam.d configuration? I must say it looks like it has nothing to do with passwords.. more of something is disabled or just a bug

Comment: Could be, but as you may know, Apple isn't very outspoken about what they do with PAM... Do you use a service such as Yubikey, or some such program that provides one-time passwords? Do you use Kerberos, or another SSO that works on Mac? (Can't be too many) EDIT: can you disable the PAM daemon in Recovery Mode?

Comment: I don't use any extra service, also I tried disabling PAM. I couldn't find the cause up to now. I'm better off with a clean reinstall + backup.

Comment: One thing you can try before reinstalling (if you haven't done already) is to simply press Enter at the password prompt, without entering anything.

Comment: @user1019780 Yes what I did was reinstalling the OS again without removing data and that seemed to be the solution, so it worked again when reinstalling the OS.